# PHP - Load image (image is on server) and insert into database as BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, image, web-services, blob

Does anybody knew how to load image (note that image is on the server) and insert int into database as blob? It's long story why I have to do this. I have tried `$myfile = file_get_contents("image.png");` and fopen, But I have problem on insert.
This is part of 'ancient' webservice that I have to use.

```
$result = mysql_query(
    'INSERT INTO dogadjaj (host_id, name, description, date, photo) 
    VALUES ("' . $host_id . '" ,"' . $name .'", "' . $description . '", "' . $date . '", "' . $myfile . '");')
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: *But I have problem on insert* what problem ?

Comment: @Ravi, ' You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2 '

Comment: When you post your question, you need to reply all the queries immediately, which was asked. We are not here to work for somebody. This shows, your are not at all serious for you issue and not trying anything

Comment: @Ravi, sorry for waiting. I have asked if anyone have this problem because I have tried several approaches then I could not find anything similar. I am not waiting for anyone to finish my job. I am not using very often stackoverflow for posting questions, so I am not really familiar with all policies here. I am so sorry for wasting your time sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem was in SQL query. If you want to put file from server to database be careful with using single quotes. So this is how it needs to be done:

```
$result = mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO dogadjaj (host_id, name, description, date, photo) 
VALUES ('" . $host_id . "' ,'" . $name ."', '" . $description . "', '" . $date . "', '" . mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents('myimage.png')) . "');")
or die(mysql_error());
```